# C# WPF - Open a sub-window from a sub-window

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm feeling silly...
I'm working on a WPF application. From my main window, I'm opening a sub-window (let's call it Win2) which contains a button to open another sub-window (it will be Win3).

From MainWindow, executing the following code opens Win2 without issue:

```
Win2 newWindow = new Win2();
            newWindow.Show();
```

But when I execute the following, from Win2, nothing happens:

```
Win3 newWindow2 = new Win3();
                newWindow2.Show();
```

Just for testing purpose, I've tried to execute this second code from MainWindow and once again it's working.

I suppose I'm missing a reference somewhere in Win2, but I don't know which.

Could someone point the obvious for me?

Thanks,

Comment: Hi, did you try set the owner? Maybe, the second windows is open behind of the first. Use TopMost property to check this.

Comment: Hello, I've checked and no, the  third window doesn't open at all.
I didn't do TopMost but I tried to bring it to front, but didn't change anything :(

Comment: Hmm, Does your constructor has the `InitializeComponent()` in win3 window?

Comment: Yes, it has...
I'm afraid I've been narrow minded in my analysis and therefore mislead you.
To move on, I've kept working on the content on Win3 by adding a new button which is not doing anything either.
I debugged in step by step mode and indeed, I'm never reaching the code at all.
Event is there, code behind is there, but nothing executes.
I'm lost!

Comment: Don't worry about it. I don't know exactly what your code do, perhaps it look like some exception. Can you show more details about your code, if possible, the method when you call Win2 and Win3?

Comment: First button was just the create of Win3 instance and showing it.
Second button to instantiate a class and add it to a list.
Nothing too specifi :-p
See the answer, I was just not using the correct event.
Thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

Ok...

I'm not sure I get it, but I found a solution.

I was using `MouseLeftButtonUp` to trigger the code and it doesn't work.
I replace it with the `Click` event, and it's working fine.

That's part of the mysteries I'll probably never get!

Thank you @Lucas Selliach for your support!

Comment: oh yeah, my pleasure.